# What are some examples of merging duplicate songs for music libraries?

Tags: data-collection, library, music

In some cases, music libraries are really big and it's no surprise you find a few compilations that share the same song.

**The idea is simple:**

*Create logic to remove the duplicate so you can save some space and have a nice and tidy music library.*

I also ask myself, *"Why do not we simply hide the duplicates?"*

Have you ever seen some good examples of this idea on any music manager software?

> <sub>***Note:***
>   
>
>   Sometimes the same songs share a title, but not the version of the record. In those cases, deeper analyzing of the needs to occur.</sub>

Comment: Welcome to UX, @Manu! This question will probably end up being closed, as it appears to be off-topic because it is asking us for specific software examples. If you would like, you can [read about what makes a question on-topic](http://ux.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Thanks @CodeMaverick, I am not exactly looking for specific examples, but design patterns that solved this issue, so my question was not well explained.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most music library managers don't handle duplicates at all because there are too many variables.  The "same" song can be recorded by the artist in many different ways - it can be part of a compilation, joined with previous tracks for a seamless audio transition, a live recording, etc.  If I was listening to the song "Wow!" on "Awesome Band Live!" and track 3 was suddenly replaced with "Wow!" from the studio recording album "Awesome Band - The Sessions", I'd be pretty disappointed in the library.

Making matters worse, when a user encodes music, each encoding can produce a different set of bytes, depending on the encoder, the parameters, the platform, the source, etc.  So I might have a duplicate copy of the studio recording of Wow! on "Awesome Band - Anthology", but because I ripped the tracks using two different programs, they don't have identical bytes.  Software so far lacks the ability to listen to music and determine that two recordings are identical - and that doesn't even get into subtle remixes that might have identical intros.

Your best bet is to aid your users in creating custom playlists easily:  tracks in album order, all tracks by an artist shuffled, all albums by an artist shuffled, but the tracks on each album remain in order, etc.  Let them know that if they delete the disliked songs from their playlists (or albums) that they can recover the data. Let them rate their songs.  Provide for easy importing from various other library managers.  Let them assign multiple categories so the same song can appear in different groups.  Make the library usable, and the duplicate issue won't be as much of a problem.

Comment: Thanks @John, thats the kind of answer I was looking for. The real issue is if the final user would be disappointed if we remove files doing an assumption that is exactly the same file, when sometimes as you argue, the version is sightly different.  As I've tried with iTunes, I've noticed that the algorithm they use is not enough accurate as I wish. But there is possible to analyze the file way deeper so we can know if there is a full match? Lenght waves vs time, cue, reverberation as well as other paramters could be compared to get a more reliable result.

Comment: That's a lot of pattern recognition you're asking for.  I know tools like Shazam can identify a specific recording, even with background noise, so it's obviously possible.  Gizmodo has this interesting article on the topic: http://gizmodo.com/5647458/how-shazam-works-to-identify-nearly-every-song-you-throw-at-it

Answer (score 0):

[iTunes does this.](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2905?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US)

You also wouldn't want to hide the duplicates. You'd want to remove them to free up HD space. Hiding them doesn't help you.